# expo local build ios TypeError at IosCredentialsManager

Tags: ios, expo

I'm trying to build expo react native app locally for ios but there seems to be error with the credentials.

```
...
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] Didn't find any issues with the project!
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Preparing credentials
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] Creating keychain
[PREPARE_CREDENTIALS] 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at IosCredentialsManager.prepare (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/ios/credentials/manager.js:66:83)
    at async /Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:48:20
    at async BuildContext.runBuildPhase (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/context.js:101:28)
    at async buildAsync (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:47:29)
    at async runBuilderWithHooksAsync (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/common.js:12:13)
    at async Object.iosBuilder (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:29:16)
    at async buildIosAsync (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/ios.js:66:12)
    at async buildAsync (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/build.js:54:29)
    at async main (/Users/anyaji/.npm/_npx/63539ccd18962a9d/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/main.js:16:9)
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Destroying keychain - /var/folders/kh/34t1kcfj44d47mr8vwj4kdlw0000gn/T/turtle-v2-20bb3dc2-39e6-460b-92d0-397ea50d0339.keychain

Build failed
Unknown error. See logs of the Prepare credentials build phase for more information.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.
```

I provided apple account info as prompted but I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean. How do I fix this? I can provide any additional information necessary. Thanks!